# How to split string into three value using list?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query which concat the row value.

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(id, ' - ', name, ' - ', status) SEPARATOR ', ') AS id_name_status
```

I want to split it as id, name and status when in HTML. Sample code is as following

```
 @foreach($results as $r)
 <?php
 $id_name_status = explode(',',  $r->id_name_status);
 foreach ($id_name_status as $id) {
 // how can i split the string into 3 value and echo it?
 }
 ?>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Why are you combining them if you're just going to split them?

Comment: So DONT concat them in the query, or leave the concat in the query BUT ADD the 3 seperate fields as well to your SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating the strings with `-` so you have to explode them with that character as well.

```
$id_name_status = explode(' - ',  $r->id_name_status);
```

**Update:**
You can also use the php [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function to store the values directly into variables.

```
list($id, $name, $status) = explode(' - ',  $r->id_name_status);
```

Comment: Probably should be `explode(' - ',  $r->id_name_status);` if you look closely

Comment: i want store in list() instead of using explode to loop through the value?

Comment: You can do that, it's just a small update. I added an example.